# CMD - Any command to copy text to clipboard?

Tags: windows, cmd, copy

Is there any command in Command Prompt (CLI) which will allow a *string of text* to be *copied* to device's **clipboard**... 
Like, for an instance,

```
@echo off
set /p text=Enter text to be copied to clipboard:
--some command here to copy the %text% to clipboard--
```

Comment: You are looking for the [`clip`](http://ss64.com/nt/clip.html) command, right? `echo %text%| clip`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To copy a command result pipe it to clip

```
dir | clip
```